# ResultSet exception - before start

Tags: java, jdbc, singlestore

```java
    public static User getUser (User user) throws Exception {
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE userID = '" + user.getuserID() + "'";
            //is FROM Correct?
            PreparedStatement pStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet Rset = pStatement.executeQuery(sql);
            Rset.beforeFirst();
            Rset.next();

            int userID = Rset.getInt("userID");
            String email = Rset.getString("email");
            User userReturn = new User (userID, email);
            return userReturn;
        }
```

```
Trace: java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed for a result set of type ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.beforeFirst(ResultSetImpl.java:426)
    at DaoLayer.daoImplementation.getUser(daoImplementation.java:28)
    at DaoLayer.DaoTest.testGetUser(DaoTest.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

Comment: I'm not sure there *is* a question, except the implicit "why am I getting this error".

Comment: Why are you even calling `beforeFirst()`? Doing that makes no sense whatsoever in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that JDBC / SQL of yours could use some updates.

But first things first. This is what happens:

```
    ResultSet Rset = pStatement.executeQuery(sql); //Executes the query
    Rset.beforeFirst(); //Moves the cursor backwards before the first row (!)
    Rset.next(); //Goes to the next row
```

The second line throws an Exeption as the cursor is FORWARD_ONLY. Plus: *You don't need that call at all!*

This should solve your immediate problem:

```
    ResultSet Rset = pStatement.executeQuery(sql);
    if(Rset.next()) {
      int userID = Rset.getInt("userID");
      String email = Rset.getString("email");
      User userReturn = new User (userID, email);
      return userReturn;
    } else {
      //Deal with no user found
    }
```

Now to the general stuff:

- it's good that you're preparing the Statement. But as Bashir already pointed out: If you go and use executeQuery(sql), which is a member of class Statement, you throw away the precompiled statement.
- when using PreparedStatement - use bind parameters as well. This makes your code less oen for SQL injection and
- use try-with-resource to make sure you close everything properly. Hunting down connection leaks or opened cursors is a hassle easily avoided.

In the end you'll probably end up with something like this:

```
public static User getUser (User user) throws Exception {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE userID = ?;
    try(PreparedStatement pStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
      pStatement.setInt(1, user.getuserID());
      try(ResultSet Rset = pStatement.executeQuery()) {  
        if(Rset.next()) {
          int userID = Rset.getInt("userID");
          String email = Rset.getString("email");
          User userReturn = new User (userID, email);
          return userReturn;
        }
      }
    } catch(SQLException e) {
      //Deal with the exception
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //Error or no user found
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create a standard `ResultSet` you can only use `rs.next()` method to iterate the resulting rows. So `rs.beforeFirst()` is not allowed.
And it is also not necessary in your code. When the `ResultSet` is created, the cursor is automatically placed before the first row. So, use just `if(rs.next()) {...}`. When `rs.next()` returns false after the first invocation, it means that the `ResultSet` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

change `pStatement.executeQuery(sql)` by `pStatement.executeQuery()`

Also `userID` is `int` so no need to use the single quote `'` in the query (but this is not the root of the `Exception`)

I suggest to use an `if` statement on `Rset.next()` (which increment cursor, no need to use `beforeFirst()`) this may cause Exceptions while getting values if the query return nothing.

Use Code as follow

```
public static User getUser (User user) throws Exception {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE userID = " + user.getuserID();
        //is FROM Correct?
        PreparedStatement pStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet Rset = pStatement.executeQuery();
        if(Rset.next())
        {
             int userID = Rset.getInt("userID");
             String email = Rset.getString("email");
             User userReturn = new User (userID, email);
             return userReturn;
        }
        return null;

    }
```